# Critical points have to be stationary?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If we find the partial derivatives of a function and set them to be 0, and the solutions are equations of the these variables instead of constant values, what can we say about the critical points?

For example, for the function $((x+1)^2+y^2+z^2)((x-1)^2+y^2+z^2)$, setting the partial derivatives to be 0 gives $(0,0,0),(\pm1,0,0),(0,y,\pm\sqrt{-y^2-1})$. Then $(0,0,0),(\pm1,0,0)$ are definitely critical points, but what can we say about $(0,y,\pm\sqrt{-y^2-1})$? Is it a critical point?

Comment: What are you trying to find?  Finding max's and min's (usually the point of recognizing critical points) in multi-variate functions involves using [Lagrange Multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)

Comment: I'm just trying to find critical points. But I don't know if the last point counts as a critical point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{-y^2 - 1}$ is not a real number, because $-y^2-1 = -(1 + y^2) < 0$, so that would not work.

On the other hand it could turn out that you get sets of critical points, which consist of many points, even such sets as curves.